# validate if names are consistent between two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames and i am trying to validate if names in both the data frames are consistent for city in "CY". considering unique id "id" and "code" between them.but i am getting error.

```
 df9 <- data.frame(id=c(4531,6846,5925,6855,7305,6918,8376,7088,6307,4452,8184,6009,6443,8737,6571,9861),
      name=c("ttt,kyy","hug,mnu","nan,look","gol,fghu","shut,juna","kkk,dhu","hbad,gyun","mund,jiha","gyth","nand,jngu","ghye,what","bhun,jkyt","bhhatn","jhtud","bhatu","jjah,dav"))
      
  df8 <- data.frame(code=c(4531,6846,5925,6855,7305,6918,8376,7088,6307,4452,8184,6009,6443,8737,6571,9861),
      city = c("CY","NY","DA","CY","MN","GA","CY","CY","NY","DA","CY","CY","GA","CY","CY","DA"),
      name=c("ttt,kyy","hug,mnu","nan,look","gol,fghu","","kkk,dhu","blal,hun","mund,jiha","gyth","","ghye,what","bhun,jkyt","bhhatn","","kling,nany","jjah,dav"))

df8 <- df8 %>%
    mutate(
      name_df8=if_else(city=="CY", name_df8, str_trim(name_df8)),
      blank = case_when(
 is.na(name_df8)~"Blank name",
 str_length(name_df8)==0~"Blank name",
 TRUE~""
      )
    )
  
df8 <- df9 %>%  
    right_join(x=.,y=select(df9,un_id_df9,name_df9), by=c(un_id_df8=un_id_df9)) %>%
    mutate(if_name_ok= case_when((is.na(name_df8) & is.na(name_df9)) | 
(is.na(name_df8) & blank=="Blank val") | 
(name_df8 == name_df9) ~ "",
name_df8 != name_df9~"Blank name",
     TRUE ~ "name not ok")) %>% select(blank,if_name_ok)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
left_join(df8, df9, by = c("code" = "id"), suffix = c("", ".")) %>% 
  mutate(
    blank = if_else(name == "", "blank name", ""), 
    consistent = if_else(name. != name & name != "", "not consistent", ""), 
    name. = NULL
  )
```

---

**Update**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

un_id_df8 = sym("code")
un_id_df9 = sym("id")
name_df8 = sym("name")
name_df9 = sym("name")
cond = expr(city == "CY")

df8 %>% 
  left_join(
    df9 %>% select(!!un_id_df9, !!name_df9) %>% mutate(temp = !!name_df9), #see here
    by = setNames(
      c(deparse(un_id_df9), deparse(name_df9)), 
      c(deparse(un_id_df8), deparse(name_df8))
    )
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    blank = if_else(!!name_df8 == "", "blank name", ""), 
    consistent = if_else(!!cond & !!name_df8 != "" & is.na(temp), "not consistent", ""), 
    temp = NULL
  )
```

Also, please ensure that your `df8` and `df9` look like something as follows. You got that unwanted `name_df8` probably because we used different dataframes. In your code above, you modified `df8`, but I used the unmodified one.

```
> df8                                 > df9
   code city       name                    id      name
1  4531   CY    ttt,kyy               1  4531   ttt,kyy
2  6846   NY    hug,mnu               2  6846   hug,mnu
3  5925   DA   nan,look               3  5925  nan,look
4  6855   CY   gol,fghu               4  6855  gol,fghu
5  7305   MN                          5  7305 shut,juna
6  6918   GA    kkk,dhu               6  6918   kkk,dhu
7  8376   CY   blal,hun               7  8376 hbad,gyun
8  7088   CY  mund,jiha               8  7088 mund,jiha
9  6307   NY       gyth               9  6307      gyth
10 4452   DA                          10 4452 nand,jngu
11 8184   CY  ghye,what               11 8184 ghye,what
12 6009   CY  bhun,jkyt               12 6009 bhun,jkyt
13 6443   GA     bhhatn               13 6443    bhhatn
14 8737   CY                          14 8737     jhtud
15 6571   CY kling,nany               15 6571     bhatu
16 9861   DA   jjah,dav               16 9861  jjah,dav
```

Output

```
   code city       name      blank     consistent
1  4531   CY    ttt,kyy                          
2  6846   NY    hug,mnu                          
3  5925   DA   nan,look                          
4  6855   CY   gol,fghu                          
5  7305   MN            blank name               
6  6918   GA    kkk,dhu                          
7  8376   CY   blal,hun            not consistent
8  7088   CY  mund,jiha                          
9  6307   NY       gyth                          
10 4452   DA            blank name               
11 8184   CY  ghye,what                          
12 6009   CY  bhun,jkyt                          
13 6443   GA     bhhatn                          
14 8737   CY            blank name               
15 6571   CY kling,nany            not consistent
16 9861   DA   jjah,dav
```

Comment: also its creating a unwanted new column "name_df8", also i want to use input parameters for code

Comment: why we are doing suffix = c("", "."))   here

Comment: i this city in Ny is missed.

Comment: Because there are two `name` columns. If you do not provide suffixes for them, they will be auto-renamed `name.x` and `name.y`.

Comment: i think i missed in data frame also , apology for that, now i have updated dataframe and objective

city in NY

Comment: NY or CY? Also, is `city` an input parameter? @newcomer

Comment: CY sorry  its CY, no city is not input parameter, its general always for all data

Comment: this is working for me but in df9 i have more columns approx (80) and while left join is also adding those column and that i dont want...

Comment: So you want only `name_df9` and `un_id_df9` to be selected? @newcomer

Comment: So you want only name_df9 and un_id_df9 to be selected?    YES
actually i dont want any column from df9 in df8 but only a mutated column for blank names name consistent